# Efficient feature selection in regression analysis

Tags: regression, correlation, feature-selection

It's a Deja Vu problem but I want to discuss in a computationally efficient perspective.

Assuming I am running a ordinary linear regression, I have hundreds of <s>factors</s> features to choose from. I want to be able to choose what <s>factors</s> features to include, if I actually include one, how would it change the $t$-statistic, $R^2$, etc. I would like to do this in an "interactive manner", i.e. I hand-pick a new one, see the updated results, etc, then de-select another old one, etc. I want to do all of these without rerunning the regression on every data point.

I imagine I should pre-dump some data such as covariance etc and compute based on such data. But I couldn't come up with an elegant solution. Can someone point me to a direction?

Comment: I think *features* is a more common term than *factors* in this context, and we have the `feature-selection` tag, so I just changed *factors* to *features* in you question.

Comment: I don't know much about this but maybe it'll get you started. When you fit a model $Y = X\beta + \varepsilon$ the standard way is to do a QR decomposition of $X$. It is possible to update this decomposition to reflect adding or deleting a column from $X$ (i.e. adding or deleting a predictor) without redoing the entire decomposition. I know Seber and Lee's _Linear Regression Analysis_ (2nd ed) has a bit on this

Comment: You want to physically be able to click on each feature and place it in or out?  Or do you just want the algorithm to be able to decide whether to place it in or out based on some criteria?